# Does a mini-ITX motherboard exist that supports more than 8 GB of memory?

Tags: memory, motherboard, mini-itx

I'm looking to assemble a new PC, and I would like it to be very energy friendly but as powerful as possible.

So I figured that the new Sandy Bridge motherboard is the way to go, preferably in a mini-ITX form factor. I've already looked at quite some options, but none of them seem to support more than 8 GB of memory.

Which brought me to this question: Are there any mini-ITX motherboards which do support more than 8 GB of memory? Or is this limited by some other factor of which I am not aware?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well I found [ZOTAC H67-ITX WiFi mini-ITX platform](http://www.zotac.com/pdbrochures/mb/master_h67itx-c-e_h67-itx-wifi_v1.2.pdf) which has the following memory specs:

> DDR3-1066/1333 **-** 2 x 240 pin DDR3 DIMM slots **-** Up to 16GB ram

and

[Intel® QM67 Mini ITX](http://www.bcmcom.com/bcm_product_mx67qm.htm) with the following memory specs:

> Two 204-pin DIMM slots support Dual Channel DDR3 SO-DOMMs 1066/1333/1600 MHz Memory up to 16 GB Max

Both of these boards have support for up to **16GB memory**.

Answer (score 2):

The limitation you are likely to run into is avalibility/cost of 8Gb DIMMs. Most ITX boards I've seen have no more than 2 DIMM slots. To reach 16Gb on those boards that support 16Gb, you need a 2x8Gb configuration.

These boards require unbuffered memory, unlike server boards, which generally use buffered memory. If you have a look around for unbuffered 8Gb DIMMS, you'll see they cost over $600 a piece.